# Laravel Basic auth:api 401 Unauthorized

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I have a Laravel 5.5 application (not using Passport) and I'm trying to access `/api` routes from a VueJS component I built using the stock infrastructure.  Using [vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) I'm not able to get a valid, authenticated response.  I can see the XSRF token being passed here:

[image]

My VueJS:

```
    methods: {
        updateSubscription(newChannelId, oldChannelId) {
            if (oldChannelId < 1 && newChannelId > 0) {
                console.log('new subscription', this);
                this.$http.post('/api/subscribe', {
                    'game_id': this.gameId,
                    'channel_id': newChannelId
                }).then(response => {
                    // success
                }, response => {
                    console.error('Failed to subscribe');
                });
```

My Laravel route in `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::post('subscribe', 'SubscriptionController@create');
    Route::post('unsubscribe', 'SubscriptionController@delete');
    Route::post('update-subscription', 'SubscriptionController@update');
});
```

I thought Laravel handled XSRF out of the gate and I wouldn't run into this issue.  I suppose I'm not 100% familiar with `auth:api` given that my http kernel looks like:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth'       => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings'   => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can'        => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest'      => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle'   => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Did you find the issue to this? I'm having the same